# How to obtain a localized string representation of the weekdays like monday, tuesday, etc.?

Tags: ios, cocoa, date, localization, nsdateformatter

How to obtain a localized string representation of the weekdays like monday, tuesday, etc.?

Sure I could localize these myself but I bet that I can suck them out from a calendar class or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a valid `NSDate`, `NSDateFormatter` can output the name of the weekday with the [date format](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/#Date_Format_Patterns) `@"EEEE"`. I don't know of a simpler way to do this in Cocoa.

Answer (score 4):

This is what you want:

```
NSArray *weekdays = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] weekdaySymbols];
NSLog(@"%@", weekdays);
```

Output:

```
(
    Sunday,
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday,
    Saturday
)
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use the [monthSymbols](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDateFormatter/monthSymbols) array from NSDateFormatter?